# How to load .ckpt, .meta output ffiles rom a TF model, input prediction data and make a prediction?

Tags: tensorflow

I followed a tutorial to use tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor to train a TF model to predict Chicago taxi fare. The model generates the following outputs in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

- checkpoint
- eval_estimator-eval/
- events.out.tfevents.1590293793.taxi-train-job-5-5qj5l
- graph.pbtxt
- model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00002
- model.ckpt-0.data-00001-of-00002
- model.ckpt-0.index
- model.ckpt-0.meta
- model.ckpt-15165.data-00000-of-00002
- model.ckpt-15165.data-00001-of-00002
- model.ckpt-15165.index
- model.ckpt-15165.meta
- model.ckpt-25000.data-00000-of-00002
- model.ckpt-25000.data-00001-of-00002
- model.ckpt-25000.index
- model.ckpt-25000.meta

Question: How can I load the model using these files, input a new data point, and make a prediction? 
Suppose these are the variables and corresponding values:

- hour_of_day: 8
- pickup_latitude: 41.5
- pickup_longitude: -87.2
- dropoff_latitude: 41.9
- dropoff_longitude: -87.1

I searched for answers online, and this is what I have now. It gave me the error message. Can anyone help and let me know how to correct it? Thank you!

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('gs://folder_name/model.ckpt-15165.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('gs://folder_name/'))

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Placeholder:0")
feed_dict = {x:[8, 41.5, -87.2, 41.9, -87.1]}



print(sess.run(feed_dict))
```

Comment: Error message:KeyError: "The name 'Placeholder:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Placeholder', does not exist in the graph."

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

There's a built in function, making it easy to make predictions.

```
    pred_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x = x_test, shuffle = False)

    predictions = estimator.predict(pred_input_func)
    for result in predictions:
        print (result)
```